# Call a function only if a variable is set to true

Tags: angularjs, methods, boolean, conditional-statements, angularjs-ng-click

I've a div on click of which I'm calling a function.

```
<div ng-click="myFunc1()">
    <!--some data here...-->
</div>

<button ng-click="stopmyFunc1===true">Cancel</button>
```

In controller :

```
$scope.myFunc1 = function(){
  if(myStr == 'abc' && stopmyFunc1 === false){
    //some code here...
  }
};
```

I need to stop executing my function on click of "cancel' button. 
But, currently with the code I've written, nothing seems to work.

How could I fix this?

Comment: You can stop execution, if you have `loop` or `promise`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the 'stop flag' directly in your click handler like this:

```
<div ng-click="stopmyFunc1 === undefined && myFunc1()">
    <!--some data here...-->
</div>

<button ng-click="stopmyFunc1 = true">Cancel</button>
```

With that you don't need an additional check in your controller...