# Call a method only if my $scope variable is false

Tags: angularjs, methods, angularjs-scope, conditional-statements, angularjs-ng-click

I've a div on click of which I'm calling a method.
Now, there's a 'Cancel' button, on click of which I'm setting a $scope.variable to true.

Next, I need to execute my function on click of the 'div', only if $scope.variable is set to false.

But it is now working! Could you help me fix this?

Here's my code:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']).controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.stopFunc = function() {
  $scope.stopFuncExec = true;
 }
 $scope.stopFuncExec == false;
 $scope.myFunc1 = function() {
  console.log("Inside " + $scope.stopFuncExec);
  var whoAreYou = "Coder";
  if (whoAreYou == "Coder" && $scope.stopFuncExec == false) {
   console.log("Hello, stop me if you can!");
  }
 }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div class="parent">
    <div ng-click="myFunc1()">Click Me!</div>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="stopFunc()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You could have edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46745248/2435473)

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry about that. But then, it was not right on my part to change my own incorrect code in the question. Hence, I added it here, Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo: `$scope.stopFuncExec == false;`

Did you mean: `$scope.stopFuncExec = false;`?

---

After `$scope.stopFuncExec == false;`  the `$scope.stopFuncExec` will be `undefined`

[Fixed Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/K1by9ZJl12jhXsvvVZHJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the function should get called only when the variable is false. I believe you can follow below work around for this. The function will get called on the click of the Div, but there you can check the condition as below.

If the variable is false, then only it will execute the block. I hope this will solve your problem.

```
$scope.myFunc1 = function() 
{
    if(!$scope.stopFuncExec)
    {
        console.log("Inside " + $scope.stopFuncExec);
        var whoAreYou = "Coder";
        if (whoAreYou == "Coder" && $scope.stopFuncExec == false) 
        {
            console.log("Hello, stop me if you can!");
        }
    }
}
```